# Creating an array from a string issue

Tags: php

I have a function that creates a multi-dimensional array from a string. Here's how the output looks like for each string:

**Strings:**

```
app.name.version

app.vendor
```

> *NOTE:* These are strings that are being retrieved from a database

**Output:**

```
['app']['name']['version']

['app']['vendor']
```

and I assign them values accordingly. The problem arises when I include numbers in the string representing an index number of a sub array. Here's an example:

```
shifts.breaks.unpaid.0.description
shifts.breaks.unpaid.0.duration
shifts.breaks.unpaid.1.description
shifts.breaks.unpaid.1.duration
```

with output:

```
Array
(
    [unpaid] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [description] => Lunch
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [duration] => 30
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [description] => Lunch 2
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [duration] => 30
                )
        )
)
```

Where it should normally look like:

```
Array
(
    [unpaid] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [description] => Lunch
                    [duration] => 30
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [description] => Lunch 2
                    [duration] => 30
                )

        )

)
```

The only thing that remedies this is if I replace the numbers with anything but numerical values like the following:

```
shifts.breaks.unpaid.b0.description
shifts.breaks.unpaid.b0.duration
shifts.breaks.unpaid.b1.description
shifts.breaks.unpaid.b1.duration

Array
(
    [unpaid] => Array
        (
            [b0] => Array
                (
                    [description] => Lunch
                    [duration] => 30
                )
            [b1] => Array
                (
                    [description] => Lunch 2
                    [duration] => 30
                )
        )
)
```

Here's the function that creates the arrays:

```
function toArray($keys, $value){
    $array = array();
    $ref = &$array;
    while(count($keys) > 0){
        $n = array_shift($keys);
        if(!is_array($ref))
            $ref = array();
        $ref = &$ref[$n];
    }
    $ref = $value;
    return $array;
}
```

Where `$keys` contains `$keys = explode('.', "my.testing.string");` and here's the example I've been working with:

```
$strings = array (
    "app.names.0.first"=> "Samuel",
    "app.names.0.last"=> "Smith",
    "app.names.1.first" => "Mary",
    "app.names.2.last" =>"Kubik"

);
$list = array();
foreach($strings as $key => $name) {
    $list[] = (toArray(explode('.', $key),$name));
}
print_r(call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $list));
```

At this point, I'm not too sure if this has something to do with `array_merge_recursive`. Any help in correcting this would be great!

Comment: _"If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended."_ http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: Rather than rolling your own, have a look and see if [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file) / [`parse_ini_string`](http://php.net/parse_ini_string) can do the job for you.

Comment: @cmbuckley I've been looking into that to be honest. The problem I sort have to live with this since the decision was to store settings in a database as a key/pair method. I do admit, parsing everything from an ini file is a lot easier...

Comment: Have a look at [this class](http://codeaid.net/php/parse-ini-file-into-a-multi-dimensional-array), or alternatively look at Zend Framework's [`Zend_Config_Ini`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html), which both do the same.

Comment: @cmbuckley is there such a framework that provides the same time of   retrieval of settings but for settings that are coming from a database? All of the settings had to be stored in a database so they can be retrieved from various remote platforms. This is why I rolled my own because I have to store some type of structure in my database and retrieve it as an array later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one solution I found was re-writing a new `array_merge_recursive` function without overwriting numeric keys.

```
function array_merge_recursive_new() {

        $arrays = func_get_args();
        $base = array_shift($arrays);

        foreach ($arrays as $array) {
            reset($base); //important
            while (list($key, $value) = @each($array)) {
                if (is_array($value) && @is_array($base[$key])) {
                    $base[$key] = array_merge_recursive_new($base[$key], $value);
                } else {
                    $base[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        return $base;
  }
```

Thanks to a user on `php.net`. This will produce the correct output when keys are numeric.